# How to make program determine largest user input

Tags: c++, function, cout, function-calls, function-prototypes

So my task is to write a program that determines which of a company's four divisions  had the greatest sales for a quarter. I am basically having an issue with the my cout statement not spitting out the location. Here is what I have:
function prototypes:

```
double getSales(string const);
void findHighest(double, double, double, double);
```

main(cannot be touched instructors commands):

```
//variables
    double nwSales, neSales, swSales, seSales, highest; 
    string const NW = "Northwest",
                 NE = "Northeast",
                 SW = "Southwest", 
                 SE = "Southeast"; 

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    nwSales = getSales(NW); // these are calls to a function that returns a value
    neSales = getSales(NE);
    swSales = getSales(SW);
    seSales = getSales(SE); 
    findHighest(nwSales,neSales,swSales,seSales);
```

function defintions:

```
double getSales(string const location)
{
    double sales;
    cout << "The " << location <<" branch had a quarterly sales figure of: $ ";
    cin >> sales;
    cout << "\n";
    while (sales < 0)
{
        cout << over3 << sales << " is not valid! Try again: "; 
        cin >> sales;
}
    return sales;
}
```

I'm pretty sure that one is right. Im having trouble with this section primarily:

```
void findHighest(double nwSales, double neSales, double swSales, double seSales)
{
system("CLS");
double highest  = nwSales;
string const location = "Northwest";

if (neSales > highest)
{
    highest = neSales;
    location = "Northeast";
}
if (swSales > highest)
{
    highest = swSales;
    location = "Soutwest";
}
if (seSales > highest)
{
    highest = seSales;
    location = "Southeast";
}
cout << down5;
cout << "The highest grossing division was " << location << "with $ " << highest;
cout << down7;

}
```

I cannot figure out why it won't tell me the location. I tried putting the cout statement in each if statement bu that messed up everything entirely. Hoping someone might be able to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: If `location` is `const`, how can you change it? Isn't the compiler complaining?

Comment: it is complaining... a lot hang on one sec

Comment: wow that solved it. thanks a bunch, I cant believe that was the only thing holding me up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string location = "Northwest";
      ^^
      no const
```

Comment: if i had enough reputation to upvote this i would... thanks again!

Comment: @user3470987: You are welcome. If this answer has helped to solve your problem, than you can "accept" the answer. An answer can be accepted by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.